# how to get a subview of UIScrollView using a CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a number of rectangular subviews lined up, of equal sizes.  Then I need to be able to pass a `CGPoint` to that `UIScrollView` and I want it to give me the rectangular subview that contains the `CGPoint`.  That's basically `hitTest:event`, except `hitTest:event:` doesn't work with `UIScrollView` once `CGPoint` goes beyond the UIScrollView bounds and doesn't look into its actual content.

What's everyone been doing about this?  How to "hit test" on a `UIScrollView` **content** view?

Here's some code to illustrate the problem:

```
NSArray *rectangles = [self getBeautifulRectangles];

CGFloat rectangleLength;
rectangleLength = 100;

// add some rectangle subviews
for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.count; i++) {
    UIView *rectangle = [rectangles objectAtIndex:i];  
    [rectangle setFrame:CGRectMake(i * rectangleLength, 0, rectangleLength, rectangleLength)];
    [_scrollView addSubview:rectangle];
}
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(rectangleLength * rectangles.count, rectangleLength)];

// add scroll view to parent view
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, rectangleLength)];
[containerView addSubview:_scrollView];


// compute CGPoint to center of first rectangle
CGPoint number1RectanglePoint = CGPointMake(0 * rectangleLength + 50, 50);

// compute CGPoint to center of fifth rectangle
CGPoint number5RectanglePoint = CGPointMake(4 * rectangleLength + 50, 50);

UIView *firstSubview = [containerView hitTest:number1RectanglePoint withEvent:nil];
UIView *fifthSubview = [containerView hitTest:number5RectanglePoint withEvent:nil];

if (firstSubview) NSLog(@"first rectangle OK");
if (fifthSubview) NSLog(@"fifth rectangle OK");
```

output: first rectangle OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to loop through the scrollview subviews

```
+(UIView *)touchedViewIn:(UIScrollView *)scrollView atPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint {

    CGPoint actualPoint = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x + scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y + touchPoint.y);

    for (UIView * subView in scrollView.subviews) {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(subView.frame, actualPoint)) {
            NSLog(@"THIS IS THE ONE");
            return subView;
        }

    }

    //Nothing touched
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: though looking at @fluidsonic answer his is more elegant for calculating the `actualPoint`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you pass the wrong `CGPoint` coordinate to the `hitTest:withEvent:` method causing wrong behavior if the scroll view is scrolled.

The coordinate you pass to this method must be in the target views coordinate system. I guess your coordinate is in the `UIScrollView`'s superview's coordinate system.

You can convert the coordinate prior to using it for the hit test using `CGPoint hitPoint = [scrollView convertPoint:yourPoint fromView:scrollView.superview]`.

In your example you let the container view perform the hit testing, but the container can only see & hit the **visible portion** of the scroll view and thus your hit fails.

In order to hit subviews of the scroll view which are outside of the visible area you have to perform the hit test on the scroll view directly:

```
UIView *firstSubview = [_scrollView hitTest:number1RectanglePoint withEvent:nil];
UIView *fifthSubview = [_scrollView hitTest:number5RectanglePoint withEvent:nil];
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work.  I'm already computing the CGPoint relative to the `UIScrollView`'s coordinates.  Besides `hitTest:withEvent:` is typically used on a superview and returns the farthest child `UIView` with userInteractionEnabled=YES.

Comment: Difficult to tell then what the bug in your implementation is without seeing the code. Please share it.

Comment: I added some code for you to take a look at.  If you think there's something else to make your approach work and avoid looping through the scroll view subviews like @Flexicoder suggested, please let me know.  I'll pick the best answer.

Comment: Still no luck.  It seems like hitTest:withEvent: only cares about the UIView bounds.

Comment: Ah that's right. To alter this behavior you'd have to subclass the scroll view and override `pointInside:withEvent:`. Return `YES` if the point is within the scroll view's `contentSize`.

Comment: Right on, good to know.  I'm going to stick with Flexi's answer on this one, but thanks for the brain pick!